# Unable to run gradlew

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I've setup a `build.gradle` file with `apply plugin: 'java'`. I tried setting up a gradle wrapper using the instructions [here](http://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/), but when I type `sudo ./gradlew build`, I get an error `sudo: ./gradlew: command not found`. When I type `gradle build`, the project builds fine. It's just gradlew that isn't working.
I even tried `sudo chmod +x gradlew` but it didn't work. I'm using Fedora 20, 64 bit and gradle version 1.10.

Comment: This doesn't really sound like a Gradle problem; you're just having trouble running a particular executable in a shell.  Why are you `sudo`-ing this?

Comment: I sudo'ed it because without the sudo, it gave this error: `bash: ./gradlew: Permission denied` and with the sudo, this error: `sudo: ./gradlew: command not found`. I'm able to run other executables, so I don't see why gradlew doesn't execute. The file begins with the line `#!/usr/bin/env bash`.

Comment: There should be no need to run gradlew via sudo, so something weird is already happening.  Can you post the result of doing `ls -l`?

Comment: Result of `ls -l` is `-rw-------. 1 nav nav  5092 Feb  6 14:46 gradlew`. This is after I did a `chmod 777 gradlew`. The files are on a Windows NTFS partition on the same system which I'm accessing from the Fedora terminal. The error is `bash: ./gradlew: Permission denied`

Comment: Hmm, your symptoms are completely consistent with this file not having `x` permission set.  So this is probably an NTFS issue then (I know nothing about mounting NTFS on Linux though...)

Comment: It's ok. Solved it. Brainstorming with you was what led me to the solution. Answer below. Thank you :)

Comment: Moving the file from an NTFS file system to ext4 was what worked for me. I have never before run into this problem.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ok so the solution was to run `gradlew` on the Linux partition itself. Somehow, when I ran it from a Windows partition mounted in Linux, the file couldn't get execute permissions even though I ran `chmod 777 gradlew`. When I copied the project into the Linux filesystem and ran it, it worked fine (after setting execute permission for it).

Comment: Even I copied to Linux drive it did not work for me. I had to clone on linux drive to run gradlew.

Comment: The mode is determined by the partition's mount options (you cannot change it via chmod).

http://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition

Comment: Interesting. This was the solution that worked for me. It seems that you cannot execute a file from a linux machine when the file is located on an NTFS (in my case) file system.