# Unable to get the gradle build running on Jenkins and Hudson

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, hudson

I installed the Gradle plugin for Jenkins but when I try to build the above project, I get this error: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21653
So I removed Jenkins and installed Hudson. I installed the Gradle plugin for Hudson but Gradle doesn't show up in the build options. So I tried running the build from the command line option that Hudson has, and it gives the following error:

> Started by user anonymous java.io.IOException: Failed to mkdirs:
>   /home/nav/tempHudsonBuild     at
>   hudson.FilePath.mkdirs(FilePath.java:852)     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1538)      at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.checkout(AbstractBuild.java:610)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:517) 
>     at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1450)      at
>   hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)       at
>   hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:82)
>     at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:137)   Finished: FAILURE

There's no lack of space or permission issue. I don't understand why these problems are happening. Could anybody help please? I've been struggling to find a solution for this for almost two days now. I'm using this jdk: jdk1.7.0_45 that came with Netbeans and I even tried building using an older Jenkins war (version 1.515), but it still didn't build. I'm on Fedora 20, 64 bit.

**Update:** The earlier build I tried with Jenkins was on the Windows partition mounted in Linux which could have had some [permission problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21598097/unable-to-run-gradlew). But even when I ran it from my Linux home folder, I got this error:

> Started by user anonymous   Building in workspace
>   /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Unite in Linux filesystem/workspace
>   [workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson6360975070832015842.sh
>   + /home/navin/git/unite/./gradlew build   /tmp/hudson6360975070832015842.sh: line 2:
>   /home/navin/git/unite/./gradlew: Permission denied   Build step
>   'Execute shell' marked build as failure   Collecting metadata...
>   Metadata collection done.   Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Not sure what's causing your problem but quite good practice is to use gradle wrapper for CI jobs (and team working as well). You don't need gradle plugin or its installation on CI machine then. Just a shell command ./gradlew <taskName>. Such approach works for me with Jenkins, I even didn't bother with trying plugin.

Comment: @topr: Actually, the update I've posted above is the output of running gradlew from Jenkins via the `Execute shell` option. This was the command I gave: `/home/navin/git/unite/./gradlew build`. When I run gradlew from the Linux terminal though, the build happens without any problem. Running it from Jenkins is where the error is happening.

Comment: Are you sure it is not permission issue? Have you tried executing this command from the same user jenkins does?

Comment: ok so since I was running jenkins with `sudo service jenkins start`, I started firefox with `sudo firefox` *(was surprised that it opened firefox without the addons that I had installed in my user account, so this was definitely running under root)* and typed `localhost:8080` to access jenkins. Still faced the same error.

Comment: And when I try the Windows version of Jenkins, everything works fine! I'd have saved days of effort if I had simply worked in Windows instead of Linux. In any case, I'd appreciate a solution to this problem, as I'll eventually prefer to work in a Linux environment.